# How to change Runnable to lambda expression in Java with IntelliJ shortcut

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

I have the following anonymous `Runnable` implementation.

```
Runnable cronTask = new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          // do something
       }
};
```

IntelliJ suggests that I replace it with a lambda expression. eg:

```
Runnable cronTask = () -> {
     // multiple "do something" statements
};
```

When using a single statement the syntax is:

```
Runnable cronTask = () -> doSomething();
```

What shortcut can I use to convert it?

Comment: `Runnable task = () -> doSomething();` or `Runnable task = () -> { multiple(); statetements(); };`

Comment: @Makoto [Good try!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132923/can-i-place-kbd-kbd-in-a-comment) ;-)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Let IntelliJ do the lifting here; you can invoke <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> on Mac) to allow IntelliJ to replace it with a lambda expression.

Comment: The only question left is why doesn’t it provide this option when hovering the mouse over the suggestion, as with most of the other code improvement suggestions (if it did, we had a consistent behavior across all Java 8 enabled IDEs)…

Comment: Old post, but where do you hold the cursor? if i press option + return . i simply break the current line.

Comment: @GillisHaasnoot:  The visual cue is usually available right there; wherever the squiggly yellow line appears is a good spot to place the cursor before invoking the above.

Comment: Yes found it. Little bulb icon appears when you hover over the affected words.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is quick action to replace the lambda inspection

Comment: Is there a shortcut to just start a lambda when writing code the first time?

Answer (score 25):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>Enter</kbd> is good way to change each one individual

but there is away to change all  lambda expression across app

```
Run Inspection by Name
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>I</kbd>

[source site](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/ctrl-alt-shift.html)

How we can use it in our Android Studio and lambda expression:

just write replace lambda as Inspection name called `anonymous type can be replaced with lambda`

List of occurrence will appear change each one manually

[Tutorial Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l63V5bZaS70)

Comment: Great answer :)